# iphone in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Are in-app purchases for a given App available to all versions of the App or only the current version?

Suppose I have MyApp 1.0 on the App Store with in-app purchases for feature A and B.

MyApp downloads a list of in-app purchase ids from a webserver.

MyApp 2.0 is released that adds support for features C and D.

My assumption is that if MyApp 1.0 queries the StoreKit for all 4 features (A, B, C and D) and Apple will happily send back all four.

Apple doesn't do any filtering on their side for you correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct; there's no way (on Apple's servers) to assign a minimum version number to an in-app product. You should take care of this when you provide the product list.